# Does Flink provide some APIs to get active data in Session Windows?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I made a Flink's Session Window to track visitor's URL in my site. And it ends after 5 minutes from beginning of inactivity( session gap )

Does Flink support some APIs to read data in active window without finishing session by session gap ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows in Flink's `DataStream` are quite flexible. For instance, you can define a custom [`Trigger`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#triggers) that emits an updated result when a records is added to a window or after a certain duration, such as every minute. In case you implement a `Trigger` that emits *early results*, you need to implement your downstream operators or logic such that it is able to deal with updated results.

If you use event-time session windows, you should be aware that session windows might be merged, i.e., depending on the session gap and the maximum out-of-orderness of the timestamps in your records, two session windows might be merged when a record is received that falls in between and "connects" them. In this case, the logic to detect an update needs to be a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: Hi Fabian. Yes Flink looks pretty flexible. But for me it means many thing to be implement. And I had spent so much to find proper examples to put custom triggers to get early results. I'd like to ask you how do you think about Apache BEAM ? Do you think it is easier way to implement triggers ?

Comment: It'll be good if you could say pros and cons when someone are making decision to use Flink's API or BEAM's API on Flink cluster.

Comment: I haven't used Apache Beam, so I cannot compare.

Comment: Okay no problem. But I'll remind your explanation when I implement custom triggers with Flink's API. I think I need to do that. Because they need be compared.